# missing ) after argument list "+" on response.write in JS

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation

```
response.write('Your case has been submitted successfully and you should receive an email notification soon.<br><br>The Case# is"+caseId+"<br><h2>title</h2>');
```

Works flawlessly if I move the concatenated value to the end of the string, but not if I want it in the middle of Text.  This is to get rendered in an iframe on a webpage

Comment: Are you intentionally using double quotes around the `caseId`? If not, that's probably your problem.

Comment: `response.write('Your case has been submitted successfully and you should receive an email notification soon.<br><br>The Case# is ' +caseId+ '<br><h2>title</h2>');` Misplaced double `"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mismatching your quotes.  You start with a single quote `'` and then use a double quote `"` in the middle.

Comment: at the time that I started writing the code also had a href tags too and was concerned that they needed to be a different operator than the string container...I'm not sure if this is the case or not

Comment: @LightweightHeavyHanded, JavaScript will take both `"` and `'` to denote string literals.  They mean the same thing in JavaScript, but you need to end the string literal with the same quote you started it with.  If within the string literal you want to use a quote mark that is also denoting the string, use a backslash before it.   For example:  `var someHtml = "<a href=\"http://www.example.com\">example.com</a>";`

Answer (score 1):

should be:

```
response.write('Your case has been submitted successfully and you should receive an email notification soon.<br><br>The Case# is'+caseId+'<br><h2>title</h2>');
```

Answer (score 0):

> '+caseId+' use single quotes here..

```
 'Your case has been submitted successfully and you should receive an email notification soon.<br><br>The Case# is'+caseId+'<br><h2>title</h2>'
```

Comment: FWIW, I also found that I need double quotes around ahref othrwise it threw that error as well.  Thx to all who answered